# Expecting results in boolean[True/False] but getting status as "None" - Why? How to resolve?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, robotframework

I execute javascript below and it must return True or False and it would do the Run Keyword If the statement is False but what in ${CheckboxStatus} is None, instead of Boolean value True or False. Kindly enlighten me on this.
Thanks.

```
 Verify Operator Checkbox
${CheckboxStatus}=      Execute Javascript  $('#operators').is(':checked')
Run Keyword If      '${CheckboxStatus}' == 'false'      Check Operator

Check Operator
Execute Javascript      $('#operators').click()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `${CheckboxStatus}` is `None` because the script provided to `Execute Javascript` doesn't return anything. To fix it, add the `return` statement:

```
Verify Operator Checkbox
${CheckboxStatus}=      Execute Javascript  return $('#operators').is(':checked')
Run Keyword If      '${CheckboxStatus}' == 'false'      Check Operator
```